# BigQuery SHA256 function

Tags: hash, google-bigquery, sha256

I need to hash some strings using `SHA256`.  Using `BigQuery` to do this results in what I understand to be a `BASE64` result, where as I need something that is different.

For example, if I want to hash "def@gmail.com" the result should be:

> c392e50ebeca7bea4405e9c545023451ac56620031f81263f681269bde14218b

But doing this in `BigQuery`:

```
SELECT SHA256("def@gmail.com") as sha256;
```

the result is:

> w5LlDr7Ke+pEBenFRQI0UaxWYgAx+BJj9oEmm94UIYs=

It's the first result that I need to get, any ideas if this is possible in `BigQuery`, I'm trying to avoid needing to use `javascript` for this.

Comment: Which API are you using? Or are you using the UI?

Comment: UI, Marcin's answer below is the correct answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I just wanted to point out that the UI (at least at the time of this writing) displays `BYTES` values as base64. The REST API also returns `BYTES` in base64 format, but that is because the data is returned as JSON.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using Standard SQL in BigQuery then you could use:

```
SELECT TO_HEX(SHA256("def@gmail.com")) as sha256;
```

results:

```
| sha256     |
| c392e50ebeca7bea4405e9c545023451ac56620031f81263f681269bde14218b |
```

Comment: This is it!  Perfect, thanks so much Marcin, really helpful.